# clipping video with ffmpeg, no output

Tags: video, youtube, ffmpeg

I downloaded this [video](http://r3---sn-4g57knzk.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?gir=yes&dur=33.200&expire=1464131964&sver=3&key=cms1&ip=79.45.22.108&sparams=clen,dur,expire,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,ipbypass,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,source,upn&fexp=9405957%2C9416126%2C9416891%2C9422596%2C9428398%2C9428657%2C9429053%2C9431012%2C9431685%2C9432423%2C9432554%2C9432684%2C9432862%2C9433096%2C9433221%2C9433774%2C9433946%2C9433968%2C9434262%2C9435527%2C9435876%2C9436097%2C9436489%2C9436835&id=o-AI5bNf9BjuJcFFVCXDC7qJF1kZfA-YKbWpabNeBnn7Uk&upn=LggmmZfbL74&pl=15&lmt=1432181616437809&clen=12080557&mime=video%2Fmp4&source=youtube&ipbits=0&signature=5C99025CC1DE2D0F5172CA0279F1C97A63A0C606.02B11501056001A5F40BC3D78F2F19C16B73624C&itag=137&redirect_counter=1&req_id=9885e1865b8da3ee&cms_redirect=yes&ipbypass=yes&mm=31&mn=sn-4g57knzk&ms=au&mt=1464115410&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjA2LmZyYTE2Kgw3Mi4xNC4yMDkuOTU)
and I used ffmpeg to clip part of the video using this command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -ss 00:05:00 -i falco.mp4 -to 00:14:00 -c copy -copyts -avoid_negative_ts 1 cut_falco.mp4
```

The output file is only 842KB, something went wrong; I don't what since I am new to ffmpeg audio/video manipolation. I need your help!

Here is a warning from the command line:

```
[mp4 @ 000000000231b100] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
```

Here is the complete [output](http://codepad.org/KVU6eYpZ) of the command line.

Here another warning from a previous version of ffmpeg, trying with the same command:

```
Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
```

Any help please!

Comment: Why `copyts`? You can drop that and add `-t 09:00` before `-i`

Comment: I think it's the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem: I was trying to cut starting from minute 5 but the video was too short (I wanted to start from second 5, misstyped).
Even though the main problem has been solved, I'm still curious about the warning, I don't get the meaning